# Need to Map two or more datasets and display as Chart using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, map-function

So, I've written a small script using Javascript, where it reads the content of the text editor and does arithmetic/other operations according to what's written in it.

Like if I type "col0 + col1", it will add the two columns and display a Pie/Bar chart.
But this is what I'm having hard time doing, "col0 + col1 + 2000", where the 2000 should be added to the final result.

```js
if (formula.split(" ")[nCnt + 1] == "+") {
    if (isNumeric(formula.split(" ")[nCnt])) {
        numTo = formula.split(" ")[nCnt];
        sym = formula.split(" ")[nCnt + 1];
        sym += numTo;

        // debugger;
    } else {
        sym = formula.split(" ")[nCnt + 1];
    }

    secondaryData[secondaryData.length - 1] = secondaryData[value].map(function (num, idx) {
        //if (isNumber(numTo)) {
            num += sym;
            res = num + secondaryData[formula.split(" ")[nCnt + 2]][idx];
            return res;
        // }
    });
}
```

My logic is, splitting everything using space. Then if there's a "+" in the next index, check if there's a number in the current index and store the value in a var.

Then using map function, add everything at last, but it performs a Var+integer thing not a integer+integer one. Also I want to know how I can add more columns to this like "col0 + col1 + col2", etc.

Comment: you want to do something like excel formula bar with text editor ?

Comment: yea sorta,ive already implemented this in table form,i just need to do in Graphical one

Comment: could you show the code behind your `isNumeric()` and `isNumber()` methods? My guess is that your numbers are coming out as strings ("var+integer thing"). You might find `parseInt(num)` helpful.

Comment: function isNumeric(n) {
            return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
        } @theholla, used parseInt,which is fine i guess

Answer (score 0):

You have the first step which is checking whether the value is a number, but in order to do math you will need to parse the value.

```
if (isNumeric(formula.split(" ")[nCnt])) {
    numTo = parseFloat(formula.split(" ")[nCnt]);
    sym = parseFloat(formula.split(" ")[nCnt + 1]);
    sym += numTo;
} else {
    sym = formula.split(" ")[nCnt + 1];
}
```

If you wanted to run this for all columns, first you would need to group them in an array, then you could run the function for each value in the array:

```
const formulas = [col1, col2, col3, col4];
for (const formula of formulas) {
    if (isNumeric(formula.split(" ")[nCnt])) {
        numTo = parseFloat(formula.split(" ")[nCnt]);
        sym = parseFloat(formula.split(" ")[nCnt + 1]);
        sym += numTo;
    } else {
        sym = formula.split(" ")[nCnt + 1];
    }
}
```

This code doesn't quite run because `nCnt` is not defined for me, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: nCnt acts as an index for a "for" loop to retrieve all the things from the text editor and check is it a number/sign or is it col,like when i type col0 + col1,then for splitting by space i check each and every thing till the index of nCnt

Comment: did parsing the value work for you @Venky? If you found another solution, you could post it as an answer here. or if not, you should post an executable snippet so others can get a better understanding of your issue. as it stands, I can't reproduce your issue because I can't run your code.

Comment: my isNumeric function does parseInt,but none the less i got it working with a diff approach,ill update soon